# pycharm 2017.1 inconsistency on directory path for loading modules

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I developed a python3 package in `Pycharm` but am running into some confusing behavior when I try to `import` modules in my test cases. The problem seems to be with the directory path to the internal package modules. It is a bit difficult to explain the issue, but here is the gist.

So the python package name is `pyugend.` Now when I try and import a module--inside the package--named `Models` into a test case, `pycharm` forces me to reference the path as `pyugend.pyugend.Models.` So I need to reference `pyugend` twice.

However, when I build, install, and import this package into a `jupyter` notebook or some script, then I run into errors about the `pyugend` package not finding the internal modules. The only way to fix these errors is to change the paths inside of the module to references like `pyugend.Models`.

So basically, to run tests inside of `pycharm` I have make sure all of the internal package imports use a directory path like `from pyugend.pyugend.Models import ...` But when I want to use the package outside of `pycharm` then I actually have to go into the package, convert all of the `import pyugend.pyugend...` references to just single `import pyugend.Models ...` references.

I have included a picture of the directory structure as well as a picture of the `__init__.py.` 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line`sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` before the imports in `__init.py__` and then change the imports to `from pyugend.Models import Base_model` and so on, to enable consistent behavior wherever you use the package.

Comment: Hey @ad22 thanks for the idea. I tried this, but still no luck.